# What does BadImageFormatException 0x80131124 (Index not found) mean?

Tags: .net, badimageformatexception

My program is occasionally crashing with the following error message:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Index not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131124)

Some details which may be relevant:

- C# 4 / .NET 4
- Windows 7 64 bit OS. EXE is for Any CPU (so it's in 64 bit mode).
- This is thrown during construction of one of my custom objects. I'm creating this object in a child AppDomain so that I can unload the DLLs which it will load by servicing the incoming request.
- I see from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yizhang/ that HRESULT 0x80131124 = CLDB_E_INDEX_NOTFOUND.
- I've only seen this happen recently (been working on this app for 3 years), and even now, it only occurs when I try profiling the tool using the Red Gate Performance Analyzer or Red Gate Memory Analyzer.

**My questions are**

- What does this mean ?
- What is the 'Index Not Found' ?
- How do I fix this ?

Thanks very much.

UPDATE

Instead of targeting the EXE for ANY, I forced it to x64. The problem still occurs.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look in your solution configuration to make sure all your projects build to the same platform.

The reason for your error is because you have a x86 file trying to load a 64bit dll or Vice versa.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How do I find out which assembly being loaded is mismatched?

Comment: I forced the app to x64 and this problem still happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your **platform target** build to **X86**

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar error due to a broken one .NET Framework. Restore via the utility [.NET Framework Repair Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135) solved the problem.

Comment: Hi Dinariys, do you have a link to something that explains this?

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no such link. Just a similar problem occurred only on one PC with Windows 7. At the same time, everything used to work on this PC, but after the next launch of Windows, an error began to appear.